# Why does this GroupLayout not resize with the window?

Tags: java, swing, jython, layout-manager

I haven't used Swing before, so I was looking at the tutorial at: 
http://www.zetcode.com/gui/jythonswing/layout/

At the bottom, there is an example that uses GroupLayout to create a simple layout that resizes with the window.  I essentially copied this example and put in my own controls and layout.  When I execute the code, however, all the controls are bunched up in the top left of the window and don't move or resize at all.

What am I missing?

code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/jython
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from java.awt import Dimension
from java.awt import Color

from javax.swing import JButton,JList
from javax.swing import SwingConstants
from javax.swing import JFrame
from javax.swing import JLabel
from javax.swing import JTextArea
from javax.swing import BorderFactory
from javax.swing import GroupLayout


class Example(JFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        layout = GroupLayout(self.getContentPane())
        self.getContentPane().setLayout(layout)
        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(True)
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(True)

        self.setPreferredSize(Dimension(350, 300))

        self.data = ("one","two","three","four")
        flist = JList(self.data)

        edit = JButton("Edit")
        grab = JButton("Grab")
        status = JLabel("status")

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(flist)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(edit)
                        .addComponent(grab)
                    )
                )
                .addComponent(status)
            )

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(flist)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(edit)
                        .addComponent(grab)
                    )
                )
                .addComponent(status)
            )

        layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, [edit, grab])

        self.pack()

        self.setTitle("Windows")
        self.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        self.setLocationRelativeTo(None)
        self.setVisible(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example()
```

Comment: Dont use `GroupLayout` this is very complex and was actually ment for IDE/GUI builder usage. But it is very powerful LayoutManager no faulting that.

Comment: Than use what?  I'm use to using Gtk (HBoxs & VBoxs).

Answer (score 0):

BorderLayout is fairly simple. Do something like:

```
 from javax.awt import BorderLayout
 from javax.swing import JButton, JFrame
 someButton = JButton("ClickMe")
 frame = JFrame("Funky Jython Program")
 frame.setLayout(BorderLayout())
 frame.add(someButton,BorderLayout.NORTH)
```

which will put a JButton at the top of the frame, and for the following buttons use EAST, SOUTH, WEST or CENTER.

Comment: I ended up using a combination of BorderLayout and GridBagLayout, though I still don't know why I couldn't get GroupLayout to work

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you only set the preferredSize.. thus, only showing you the size you preferred.. to resize,  you should also include MinimumSize and MaximumSize so that when you make the frame smaller/bigger, components will follow.

PS:
hjek - man, the person is asking about GroupLayout; he was not asking about the BorderLayout. your answer is illogical.

Comment: do you think or do you know?